# How correctly remove entity from model in relationship one to many EF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have to models:

```
public class DeviceType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DeviceTypeId { get; set; }

    public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
}
```

with relationship one to many. My fleunt api configuration looks like this:

```
class DeviceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
{
    public DeviceConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(d => d.DeviceType)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeviceTypeId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

I don't want delete cascade my devices when I delete type of device. I want if type not used in Devices table delete him correctly else if type used throw exception. In this configuration all works well until I try delete used in devices table type after this removing I can't delete any type at all - always throws exception in SaveChanges.

**EDIT 1**:
Exception:

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Devices_dbo.DeviceTypes_DeviceTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "xxx", table "dbo.Devices", column 'DeviceTypeId'.
The statement has been terminated.

**EDIT 2**: I understand what happened, when I try delete entity who used in another table it's mark State.Deleted in SaveChangeAsync() it's throw Exception (normally), but when I try delete another entity who not used in another table, first entity stay in State.Deleted and SaveChanges() again throw exception. What corret whay to solve this problem? Reset Entity to Unchanged State?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: If you want to manipulate several entities and be sure to succeed all, except for not allowed ones. You can try to call SaveChanges() after every update, catch a occurred Exception and throw it further only if it's not because of referential integrity.

Comment: Or you check if the type is referenced, before you remove it, so you can prevent any Exception of this cause.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I added Edit in quiestion

Comment: Can you add Code, where you try to remove several objects?

Comment: Reset to Unchanged status would be a good attempt. Have you ever tried it?